# Windows explorer crashes & restarts when I try to open a video file in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

My Dell Laptop XPS has Windows 8.1 as its OS. Whenever I open Windows Explorer and try to open a Quicktime Player file or an MP4 file, Windows explorer crashes, BSOD appears for a few seconds and then my regular desktop reappears with all open programs running. If I reopen Windows Explorer, the same episode reoccurs.
I have tried recovering the missing files through Update and Recovery Tab of PC Settings, but a message appears saying " Some files are missing. Please load media." I don't have any Windows CD as it was installed by downloading it from the web. If someone has a solution to this problem, please advise.

Comment: create a dump of the crashing Explorer and share it: http://pastebin.com/WACz5GBU

Answer (score 1):

If it crashes before you launch the movie file (only when selecting it), it's a preview problem.
Open Folder Options and click/tap on the View tab
Check Always show icons, never thumbnails, and click/tap on OK.
That'll fix it.

If it crashes after you start the movie (or exactly at that point), you will need to install a video player or update the current one, since it's most likely a player-related problem.